# How to use functions in Javascript to bulid an interactive text?

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters

I'm trying to build an interactive text with Javascript. I can do it by using a new function each element I create, but if I do that I'll have too many functions.

Could somebody tell me what is wrong with the following code and what I should do so it works?
Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <p>Name:</p>
        <button id="peter" onclick="includeName1(peter)">Peter</button>
        <button id="paul" onclick="includeName1(paul)">Paul</button>
        <p>Wife's name</p>
        <button id="mary" onclick="includeName2(mary)">Mary</button>
        <button id="emma" onclick="includeName2(emma)">Emma</button>
        <p>How long have you been married?</p>
        <input id="years" type="number" oninput="includeTime()">
        </div>
        <br/>
    
        <div>
        <p>My name is&nbsp;<span id="name1"></span>.&nbsp;I'm married to&nbsp;<span id="name2"></span>. We've been married for&nbsp;<span id="time"></span>&nbsp;years.
        </p>
        </div>   
                
        <script>
            function includeName1(manName){
                if (manName == "peter") {
                    document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML = "Peter";}
                else if (manName == "paul") {
                    document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML = "Paul";
                }
                }
            
            
            function includeName2(womanName){
                if (womanName == "mary") {
                    document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML = "Mary";}
                else if (womanName == "emma") {
                    document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML = "Emma";
                }
                }
             
            
            function includeTime(){
                var x = document.getElementById("years").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = x;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the names in apostrophes, at the moment you're trying to pass an object called 'peter' to the function. On the input, you need to use `value` instead of `innerHtml`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <p>Name:</p>
        <button id="peter" onclick="includeName1('peter')">Peter</button>
        <button id="paul" onclick="includeName1('paul')">Paul</button>
        <p>Wife's name</p>
        <button id="mary" onclick="includeName2('mary')">Mary</button>
        <button id="emma" onclick="includeName2('emma')">Emma</button>
        <p>How long have you been married?</p>
        <input id="years" type="number" oninput="includeTime()">
        </div>
        <br/>
    
        <div>
        <p>My name is&nbsp;<span id="name1"></span>.&nbsp;I'm married to&nbsp;<span id="name2"></span>. We've been married for&nbsp;<span id="time"></span>&nbsp;years.
        </p>
        </div>   
                
        <script>
            function includeName1(manName){
                if (manName == "peter") {
                    document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML = "Peter";}
                else if (manName == "paul") {
                    document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML = "Paul";
                }
                }
            
            
            function includeName2(womanName){
                if (womanName == "mary") {
                    document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML = "Mary";}
                else if (womanName == "emma") {
                    document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML = "Emma";
                }
                }
             
            
            function includeTime(){
                var x = document.getElementById("years").value;
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = x;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck with that for a long time!

Answer (score 0):

For the record...
this code should be more readable on this way:

```js
const inTexts = document.getElementById('interractiv-texts')
  ,   outText = document.getElementById('Out-Text')
  ,   tVals   = {  man: '', wife: '', years: '' }
  ;
const setText = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('[data-part]')) return
  tVals[e.target.dataset.part] = e.target.value
  outText.textContent = `My name is ${tVals.man}, I'm married to ${tVals.wife}. We've been married for ${tVals.years} years.`
  }
inTexts.oninput = setText
inTexts.onclick = setText
```

```html
<div id="interractiv-texts">
  <p>Name:</p>
  <select data-part="man">
    <option value="Peter">Peter</option>
    <option value="Paul">Paul</option>
    <option value="John">John</option>
  </select>
 
  <p>Wife's name</p>
  <button value="Mary" data-part="wife">Mary</button>
  <button value="Emma" data-part="wife">Emma</button>
  <p>How long have you been married?</p>
  <input data-part="years" type="number" >
</div>

  <p id="Out-Text"></p>
```